# sympy - taking derivative of sum of symbolic number of elements

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to find the closed form solution of the derivative of a sum of symbolic number of elements. But the results obtained from my code is not correct.

```
from sympy import *
i, n = symbols('i n')
s, x = symbols('s x', cls=Function)
s = summation(x(i), (i, 1, n))
frac = x(i)/s
diff(frac,x(i))
```

It's easy to derive that the correct result should be:

[image: equation1]

but the above code actually gives me is:

[image: equation2]

(I apologize if the Latex code is not rendered correctly, thank you for eye-rendering it..)
There is a similar post here but their problem is different: the derivative is taken over a parameter, not $x(i)$, one of the element.

Wonder why this occurred?

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference, but maybe differentiate wrt x(j) instead of x(i) to avoid confusion of same symbol i within and without summation.

Answer (score 2):

I find it very hard to parse your LaTeX but it seems like when I try this I get what you said you expected to see (maybe that's the wrong way round). By the way a better way to demonstrate this on SO is to use SymPy's pretty-printing feature (e.g. `pprint` or `init_printing`):

```
In [8]: frac
Out[8]: 
   x(i)   
──────────
  n       
 ___      
 ╲        
  ╲       
  ╱   x(i)
 ╱        
 ‾‾‾      
i = 1     

In [9]: diff(frac, x(i))
Out[9]: 
          n                 
         ___                
         ╲                  
          ╲                 
   x(i)⋅  ╱   1             
         ╱                  
         ‾‾‾                
        i = 1         1     
- ───────────── + ──────────
              2     n       
  ⎛  n       ⎞     ___      
  ⎜ ___      ⎟     ╲        
  ⎜ ╲        ⎟      ╲       
  ⎜  ╲       ⎟      ╱   x(i)
  ⎜  ╱   x(i)⎟     ╱        
  ⎜ ╱        ⎟     ‾‾‾      
  ⎜ ‾‾‾      ⎟    i = 1     
  ⎝i = 1     ⎠
```

Firstly you need to understand that in SymPy if `x` is a function then `x(i)` is the function evaluated at `i`. If you want to use `i` to index different variables then you should declare `x` as `IndexedBase` rather than `Function` and then use square subscript brackets. Also there can be a confusion between free and bound symbols so it is better to use different symbols here for the (bound) summation variable and the variable that you differentiate wrt:

```
In [15]: x = IndexedBase('x')

In [16]: j = symbols('j')

In [17]: s = Sum(x[j], (j, 1, n))

In [18]: frac = x[i] / s

In [19]: frac
Out[19]: 
   x[i]   
──────────
  n       
 ___      
 ╲        
  ╲       
  ╱   x[j]
 ╱        
 ‾‾‾      
j = 1     

In [20]: diff(frac, x[i])
Out[20]: 
         n                    
        ___                   
        ╲                     
         ╲   δ                
  x[i]⋅  ╱    i,j             
        ╱                     
        ‾‾‾                   
       j = 1            1     
- ─────────────── + ──────────
               2      n       
   ⎛  n       ⎞      ___      
   ⎜ ___      ⎟      ╲        
   ⎜ ╲        ⎟       ╲       
   ⎜  ╲       ⎟       ╱   x[j]
   ⎜  ╱   x[j]⎟      ╱        
   ⎜ ╱        ⎟      ‾‾‾      
   ⎜ ‾‾‾      ⎟     j = 1     
   ⎝j = 1     ⎠
```

That looks correct to me (note the upper sum has a Kronecker-delta).