# Differentiating a sum in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, differentiation

I would like to differentiate the entropy H(T) of a discrete random variable T with respect to one of the masses q(t') using Sympy.
The following implements the expression for H(T):

```py
import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing(use_latex=True)

N_T = sym.Symbol("N_T")
qT = sym.Function("q")

t = sym.Symbol("t")
ht_expr = sym.summation( qT(t) * sym.log(qT(t)), (t, 1, N_T) )
ht_expr
```

This prints the correct expression for H(T), as expected:

[image]

Now, differentiating with respect to q(t') should result in the derivative of q(t)log(q(t)) evaluated at t' if t' is in 1...N_T, and 0 otherwise (this is a known result, easy to check). I.e. it should return:

[image]

Instead I get 0:

```py
tprime = sym.Symbol("t'")
sym.diff(ht_expr, qT(tprime))
[Out]: 0
```

How can I make Sympy handle sums like this and give the correct result?

Comment: well... `q(t')` is not part of the `ht_expr`-expression hence the derivative will be zero

Comment: Analytically it will not. It will be del_{t, t'}*derivative of q*log. I do not know how to make sympy do this. Humans do it, so it should be possible ;)

Comment: compute `ht_expr.diff(qT(t))` and evaluate at different `t`s

Comment: I don't know you mean by analytically, taking the derivative of an expression wrt a variable not included in the expression itself will be always 0. An expected result of the derivative would useful

Comment: @cards The point is that the variable can in principle be there. A case with simpler notation would be: consider three variables x_1, x_2, x_3. Consider `f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = Sum_k(x_k)`. Then `d/dx_r (f) = 1 if r is in 1,2,3`.

Comment: In my case, you can see H(T) as a function of N_T variables $q(1), ..., q(N_T)$. (Note that you can see each pmf component q(t) as a different variable in the N_T-dim euclidean space because we're dealing with discrete variables).

Answer (score 2):

I found that the answer in [sympy - taking derivative of sum of symbolic number of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114483/sympy-taking-derivative-of-sum-of-symbolic-number-of-elements) also applies to this case.

In short, we need to use `IndexedBase` instead of `Function`.
For completeness, here is the code solving this problem.

```py
N_T = sym.Symbol("N_T")
qT = sym.IndexedBase("q")
t, k = sym.symbols("t k")

ht_expr = sym.summation( qT[t] * sym.log(qT[t]), (t, 1, N_T) )
sym.diff(ht_expr, k)
```

Output:

[image]